# What kinds of patterns can RKeys#deleteByPattern(String pattern) take?

Tags: reddison

What type of pattern can be passed? Examples: regex, wildcard, etc.
I have not been able to find a java doc or other documentation detailing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the javadoc [in the source code](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson/blob/950308956a3b135c718ff4842659e4087e1178a5/src/main/java/org/redisson/api/RKeysReactive.java#L84):

deleteByPattern supports these glob style patterns:

```
 h?llo subscribes to hello, hallo and hxllo
 h*llo subscribes to hllo and heeeello
 h[ae]llo subscribes to hello and hallo, but not hillo
```